# azure-sdk-for-node: virtualMachines.get does not return VM status (stopped, running, deallocated, etc.)

Tags: azure-node-sdk

I've made the call to virtualMachines.get to retrieve instance information about my VM. In the output I don't see where you get the status of the VM (stopped, running, deallocated). Is there another way to get the status that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

use the optional query parameter $expand=instanceView.

Example:

```js
//assuming you have instantiated the client ...
let options = {expand: 'instanceView'};
client.virtualMachines.get('rg-name', 'vm-name', options).then((vminfo) => {
  console.dir(vminfo, {depth: null, colors: true});
}).catch((err) => {
  console.dir(err, {depth: null, colors: true});
});
```

Documentation found [here](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-compute/latest/VirtualMachines.html#get).